# CSS: Adjust alignment of inline items on wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, text-alignment

I have two items that represent checkboxes displayed as inline-block. On a wide screen they should be displayed in one line next to each other. Both should be centered.

```
Good: 

|-----itemX--itemXYZ-----|
```

On smaller screens I want them to be displayed on top of each other, still centered on screen but aligned to the left:

```
Good:

|--itemX----|
|--itemXYZ--|
```

What I am able to get at the moment is just:

```
Bad:

|---itemX---|
|--itemXYZ--|
```

How could I achieve this with CSS(3)?

PS: I'm using BootStrap 3, maybe this could be helpful...

HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <div class="cb"></div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS so far:

```
#form {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

    @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
        //
    }
}

.cb {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You should use media queries to do that.

Comment: @ArunKumarM: Not much to share so far, anyway I've edited my question :)

Comment: do not use text-align center, instead use margin: 0 auto; and width for from

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for that task.

```css
        .checkbox{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 480px) {
            .checkbox{
                display: block;
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="checkbox text-center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox text-center">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> Checkbox 2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tex-align:center` try below

```css
#form {
    display: block;    
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
    <div class="cb">itemX</div>
    <div class="cb">itemXYZ</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Sample</title>
<style>
    *{box-sizing:border-box;}
    #form{
        text-align:center;
    }
    .cb{
        width:50%;
        text-align:left;
        display:inline-block;
    }

    .cb:first-child{text-align:right;}


    @media (max-width:320px){
        .cb:first-child{text-align:left;}
        .cb{width:100%;}
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
    <div class="cb"><label class="cb-inner"><input type="checkbox">short label</label></div>
    <div class="cb"><label class="cb-inner"><input type="checkbox">longer label label</label></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```